# Bootstrap rendering narrow on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

My page is rendering extremely narrow on chrome.  It wasn't doing this before I edited it, and the +1 button was the only thing I added.  However commenting out that doesn't seem to fix it. Can anyone guide me into what's exactly wrong here?  I've tried tracking this but I'm at a total loss.

[Site](http://afny.net/afny)

[extra Css](http://afny.net/afny/css/afny.css)

[image]

Comment: It also seems to be rendering backwards...hmmmm

Comment: That's from the front facing camera of my laptop.  Disregard RTL text haha

Comment: @JordanD ¿ʎɐs noʎ spɹɐʍʞɔɐq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.main-body {
   padding: 20px 160px 0px 160px;
}
```

You should use a media query to clear this on mobile.

Example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:screen-xs-max){
   .main-body{padding:0px;}
}
```

I always recommend using a container instead of a custom class. If you are using a row property without the container you aren't using Bootstrap properly. Main-body should be replaced with container. Then you set the widths on the container for each breakpoint. Solves a ton of headache and it's proper for Bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for the quick lesson.  It was weird even when I commented out main body in the css it seemed to mess up, but maybe it was the cached copy.  I set it to container fluid, starting to clean up the code a little.  Now I'm going to try to mess with a media query so when the min-width is over 900 or so I'll add padding.  Thanks.  This shows I need to restart my Treehouse CSS course ;)

Comment: You have it set to the `body` element too. `Container-fluid` is full width. `Container` is a set width depending on the breakpoint. You need to restart your Bootstrap course :)

Comment: Well what I actually did is set it to the body.  I set margins on the body like this:

    `@media screen and (min-width:900px){

       body{margin:20px 160px 0px 160px;}

    }`

Comment: And quite honestly, I've never taken a bootstrap course, nor do I intend to in the end I don't think.  It's just handy to put something up quick, I'll work on the site later.

Comment: What I am saying is that `container` negates the need for margins or padding anywhere else.

Comment: Oh, I understand now.  Thanks.  I didn't realize the difference :)